# Elastic Beanstalk Domain Name

Tags: amazon-web-services, elastic-beanstalk

I'm new to AWS Elastic Beanstalk.
So i've confused, when i want to create new environment, in the Domain if i use
**mydomain.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com** it can be done.
But when I try to use like subdomain >> **subdomain-1.mydomain.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com** it become error "Value subdomain-1.mydomain at 'CNAMEPrefix' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must contain only letters, digits, and the dash character and may not start or end with a dash".
What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS do not support hosts on this way. You define host (**NOT DOMAIN!!!**) `mydomain.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com`. So you should create domain `mydomain.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com` to create there new host in this domain. Which is not supported.

What you can do is to create new host with name  `subdomain-1-mydomain.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com`

Comment: My goal is to get CNAME subdomain-1.mydomain.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com. How can I do that?

Comment: @Sinauwae, as I explain already you can't.

Comment: But I see at their example pic >> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customdomains.html 
GettingStartedApp-env.bx7dx222kw.us-east2.elasticbeanstalk.com my goal is to make it like that.

Comment: @Sinauwae, you can try in Amazon Route 53 to arrange the things. Or contact Amazon support.